# SQL : Replace integer with string when there is empty value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am doing something very similar to this SO thread ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924442/sql-select-replace-integer-with-string)). The difference is that my table sometimes has empty value. Here is the illustration below following the link that I provide.

1) Table 'people' that contain list of people with their favorite sport

```
ID | Name  | FavSport | DislikeSport
------------------------------------
1  | Bob   |    1     |      5
2  | Roy   |    3     |      4
3  | Sarah |          |       
4  | Kevin |    2     |      
5  | Mary  |          |      3
```

2) Table 'sports' that show the list of the sport

```
ID |   Sport    
---------------
1  | Football   
2  | Basketball  
3  | Volleyball  
4  | Soccer    
5  | Badminton
```

The query I get from the link I post in this thread

```
select people.Name, sports.Sport 
from people, sports 
where people.FavSport = sports.ID
```

3) The Result if the query similar like above

```
Name  | Sport      | Dislike
----------------------------
Bob   | Football   | Badminton 
Roy   | Volleyball | Soccer    
Sarah | Football   | Football   
Kevin | Basketball | Football   
Mary  | Football   | Volleyball
```

4) What I want is empty like below (or any default value like : nothing)

```
Name  | Sport      | Dislike
----------------------------
Bob   | Football   | Badminton 
Roy   | Volleyball | Soccer    
Sarah |            | 
Kevin | Basketball | 
Mary  |            | Volleyball
```

Anyone how to deal with this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an outer join

```
select people.Name,
       likes.Sport as FavSport ,
       dislikes.Sport as DislikeSport
from people
left join sports likes
on people.FavSport = likes.ID
left join sports dislikes
on people.DislikeSport = dislikes.ID
```

Standard Docs for [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: My case is actually the people table also have 'Dislike Sport', the opposite of 'FavSport' that also use the sport table. Do you know how can I JOIN it?

Comment: @Tan - can you post that in the question, the table structure along with sample data.

Comment: Edited above, that is much more similar like my database

Comment: @Tan - Updated answer

Comment: Why there is 'likes' and 'dislikes' table?

Comment: @Tan - those are not tables, those are `alias` names for the tables. link to read - https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT people.NAME, 
       Isnull(sport.sport, '') AS Sport 
FROM   people 
       LEFT JOIN sport 
              ON favsport = sport.id
```

Comment: I edit my post, so actually I have two field, favorite and dislike, that both of them take the sport list from 'sport' table, do you know how to JOIN it?

Comment: `NULL` and `''` are _different.  Do the appropriate test.  (Or test for both.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a [`left outer join`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

```
select people.Name, sports.Sport 
  from people
  left join sports on (people.FavSport = sports.ID);
```

Comment: My case is actually the people table also have 'Dislike Sport', the opposite of 'FavSport' that also use the sport table. Do you know how can I JOIN it?

Comment: Just join it again. You'll have to give the two versions of 'sports' a different alias but other than that it's just like another table.